# Why are IE & Safari are not aligning this element to center?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

http://meowzen.com/pacific-wild.org/initiatives

This is how it should be displayed (and is displayed in Firefox & Chrome):
[image: Firefox & Chrome]

However, both IE & Safari are aligning this way:
[image: Safari & IE]

Any ideas how we can align the IE & Safari "Learn More" button to center?

*p.s. This is a responsive layout.*

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: That's a pretty sweet picture of the urchins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is why it DOES work in firefox and chrome, since I don't see any horizontal positioning showing up.  Does this work?

```
    .image-banner .mw-qf {left: 50%;}
```

Comment: It's aligning center because .image-banner {text-align: center;}, but yes! This did fix it while not making a change in Firefox & Chrome. Thank you!